# VisualForce Datepicker

Tags: visualforce, date-picker

When I use

`<apex:inputField value="{!DateOfBirth}" label="Date of birth"/>`

I can not pick privious year

[image: date picker]

How I can pick 1960 year

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(false, this, false);"

`<apex:inputField value="{!DateOfBirth}" label="Date of birth" onfocus="DatePicker.pickDate(false, this, false);"/>`

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $j = jQuery.noConflict();
    $j(document).ready(function() {
        var cYear = new Date().getFullYear() ;
        var startYear=(cYear - 110);
        var endYear=(cYear + 25);
        var htmlStr='';
        if(startYear<endYear){
            for(i=startYear;i<endYear+1;i++){
                htmlStr += "<option value=\""+i+"\">"+i+"</option>";
            }
            $j('#calYearPicker').html(htmlStr);
        }
        $j('#sidebarDiv #hideThisHomePageComp').parent().parent().hide();
    } );
</script>
```